# how to put code in stack overflow nowadays?

Tags: discussion, design

I tried to copy this html into a code (enter code here) thingy and it loses the closing div like this:

```
    <div class="wrapper">
    <img src="https://recodetech.files.wordpress.com/2014/05/early-vehicle-lores.jpg?quality=80&strip=info" alt="">
    <img src="https://recodetech.files.wordpress.com/2014/05/early-vehicle-lores.jpg?quality=80&strip=info" alt="">
    <img src="https://recodetech.files.wordpress.com/2014/05/early-vehicle-lores.jpg?quality=80&strip=info" alt="">
</div>
```

I click the brackets and it says, enter code here and I paste it. I'm using Windows 8.1 and Google Chrome 43.0.2357.134 m... If I mark the pasted data and hit the bracekts again it works... but should work directly I assume. Anyone else same problem?

Please help!

Answer (score 4):

You seem to have achieved it. But for future references, you could either press **CTRL + K** or click the brackets icons **{ }** above the text area bar or you could open and close **< code >** **< / code>**.

Answer (score 2):

1 - copy and past your code first.
2 - Then highlight it.
3 - click the {} above the input field.

Comment: edit your question with some new code and try it out.

Comment: if I copy the code above and click the brackets and paste it, my problem occure again... but if I mark my code and then click brackets it works. Probably a bug, you get the same error?

Comment: I just edited your code using the process, it works for me :/

Comment: ok, it doesnt for me, I'm on windows 8.1 using Google Chrome 43.0.2357.134 m ... I copy the code with the ending div and I open a new sheet, click the brackets and paste it and the ending div dissappears.

Comment: Lets blame it on windows 8! lol, sorry, I am a failure :(